# Cannot swap values on next.js app front-end even though swap function works on the back-end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've created a currency converter app with next.js. It works fine. However I also try to insert a functionality that allows users to swap From and To currencies back and forth.

**This is the function code:**

```
const swapCurrencies = () => {
  setConvertFrom ( 
    (prevState) => { 
      console.log("setting convertForm state:", convertTo)
      return convertTo
    }
  );

  setConvertTo ( 
    (prevState) => { 
      console.log("setting convertTo state:", convertFrom)
      return convertFrom
    }
  );
};
```

**This is the button:**

```
  <button onClick={swapCurrencies}>
    Swap
  </button>
```

**These are input fields for From and To currencies:**

```
    <Input
      label="From:"
      dropdown={true}
      onChange={setConvertFrom}
      symbols={symbols}
    />
    <Input
      label="To:"
      dropdown={true}
      onChange={setConvertTo}
      symbols={symbols}
    />
```

**Related snippet of input.js file:**

```
    {(dropdown && (
      // Dropdown list for From & To currencies
      <select name="countries" onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)} className="px-4 py-2 rounded-xl">
      {arrOfSymbols.map((symbol) => (
        <option value={symbol} key={arrOfSymbols.indexOf(symbol)}>
          {symbols[symbol]}
        </option>
      ))}
```

**QUESTION EDITED:**
I can succesfully swap values now as I've been inspecting on the console. However I cannot "visually" swap them. Dropdown currency list displays values as not swapped. When I try to convert an amount, it also works as swapped.

[image: screenshot]

I've tried to assign `key={value}` to `<Input/>`s. This didn't change anything at all.

```
<Input
  key={setConvertFrom}
  label="From:"
  dropdown={true}
  onChange={setConvertFrom}
  symbols={symbols}
/>
<Input
  key={setConvertTo}
  label="To:"
  dropdown={true}
  onChange={setConvertTo}
  symbols={symbols}
/>
```

Can anyone advice me on what should I try to make this function fully work?

Comment: Seems like issue is related to the way you're updating the state in your swapCurrencies function. setState is asynchronous in React, you can't rely on the updated state immediately after calling setState. Instead, you could try the functional form of setState.
```setState(prevState => newState)```

Answer (score 1):

The useState hook is not synchronous. You cannot print the console log just after the setState and get the updated value because it was not updated yet.

However, you can use the useState function assignment like this and put the console log inside the function, there you will see the value just before the change:

```
setConvertFrom( 
    (prevState) => { 
        console.log("setting convertForm state:", convertTo)
        return convertTo
    }
);
```

and, you can use the useEffect hook in order to listen to the state after the change

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("After Swap:", convertFrom, convertTo);
}, [convertFrom, convertTo])
```

Comment: I've modified my code as you have explained and now the functionality works but values are not changing on UI. Input fields still show Before Swap currencies. Do you think that I also need to edit my input fields code above or input.js?

Answer (score 0):

**Previous answer:**

If you are worry about the visual change or render or the both Input, You have to provide a `key` props to each of the Input Components.

```
<Input
  key={convertFrom}
  label="From:"
  dropdown={true}
  onChange={setConvertFrom}
  symbols={symbols}
/>
<Input
  key={convertTo}
  label="To:"
  dropdown={true}
  onChange={setConvertTo}
  symbols={symbols}
/>
```

**Edited Answer:**

So i am slightly changing the approach.

***Input.js***

```
<div>
  <h1>{label}</h1>
  {dropdown && (
    <select
      name="countries"
      onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
      className="px-4 py-2 rounded-xl bg-block"
      value={defaultValue}
    >
      {/* previous codes */}
    </select>
  )}
</div>
```

***Parent.js***

```
const [convert, setConvert] = useState({
    from: 'usd',
    to: 'yen',
  })
  const swapCurrencies = () => {
    setConvert((prevValue) => ({
      from: prevValue.to,
      to: prevValue.from,
    }))
  }
```

***Both inputs***

```
    <INPUT
      key={1}
      label="From:"
      defaultValue={convert.from}
      onChange={(data) =>
        setConvert((prevValue) => ({ ...prevValue, from: data }))
      }
    />
    <INPUT
      key={2}
      label="To:"
      defaultValue={convert.to}
      onChange={(data) =>
        setConvert((prevValue) => ({ ...prevValue, to: data }))
      }
    />
```

I hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: Actually this messed up the UI. I'm receiving the following warning: _Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `ANG`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted_

Comment: I assigned `key` to `setConvertFrom` and `setConvertTo`. UI has been fixed but the input fields still don't visually swap.

Comment: Actually in my case, i initiated the convertTo and convertFrom with different value, thats why they didn't get the error.
SO, i have edited my answer, i am suggesting a new approach, i hope you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

you should create a different question for a different problem or topic.

However, I can see that your input control is setting the options using this var: `symbols`

So, if you are not changing that var, the options wont change.

maybe you should use the state that you changed: `convertTo` like this:

```
<Input
  key={setConvertTo}
  label="To:"
  dropdown={true}
  onChange={setConvertTo}
  symbols={convertTo}
/>
```

and the second input like this:

```
<Input
  key={setConvertFrom}
  label="From:"
  dropdown={true}
  onChange={setConvertFrom}
  symbols={convertFrom}
/>
```

Maybe you will need to format those values `convertFrom`, `convertTo` before passing them to the input as the symbols.

Note: The key must be a value, the same value for the same element always. They are used by react in order to decide if it is the same element and if it is necessary to render the component again. So, they affect the performance and that is the reason they are important and should be unique and remain as the same for the same element.
So, this is wrong:

```
<Input
 key={setConvertTo}   // <-- this is a function and it is returning a value that changes for the same element, that is wrong (and I think it is also an array, not just a single value, that is wrong as well)
```

it should be something like this:

```
<Input
 key='setConvertTo_Input'  // <-- this is a string value and it will remain the same for the same input always
```